# Java : Assign value of string to new string inside loop for

Tags: java

I'm new in java and I'm trying to assign value of string to another string inside looping for, and this is the example:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

      int j = 100;
      int k = 20;
      String n0 = "&";
      String n1 = "|";
      String n2 = "^";
      String n3 = "~";
      for(int n = 0; n < 4; n++)
      {
        if(n < 3){
            String operator = "n"+n;
            System.out.println(operator);    
        }
      }
}
```

I've **expected** result like this:

> & | ^

But I got this as the **actually** result:

> n0 n1 n2

How do I can get the result as the expected? and can anybody explain why I got this as result?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a variable using its name, you need for example to store them in an array :

```
String[] operators = {n0, n1, n2, n3};
// or directly 
//String[] operators = {"&", "|", "^", "~"};
for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++) {
    if (n < 3) {
        String operator = operators[n];
        System.out.print(operator);
        // or directly 
        //System.out.print(operators[n]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to access to your variables by name and this is not possible, instead you can create a map which hold the key `n1, n2, ..`, and the expected value like so :

```
Map<String, String> map = Map.of("n0", "&", "n1", "|", "n2", "^", "n3", "~");
```

then you can get the value :

```
String operator = "n" + n;
System.out.println(map.get(operator));
```

---

The full code can just be like so :

```
Map<String, String> map = Map.of("n0", "&", "n1", "|", "n2", "^", "n3", "~");
for (int n = 0; n < map.size(); n++) {
    if (n < 3) {
        System.out.println(map.get("n" + n));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use an array, please see:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Try ussing the "ArrayDemo" example but change the line

```
    int[] anArray;
```

Into:

```
    String[] anArray;
```

and fix the errors it may produce.

Toodles

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is printing the String "n" concatenated with your current loop index. You run this loop 3 times, for the indices 0, 1 and 2. That's why you get "n0" "n1" and "n2" as result. If you actually want to access your variables with a loop you need to put them in a suitable data structure like an array (as stated by others). If you want to put your Strings into an array you can use the following example:

```
String n0 = "&";
String n1 = "|";
String n2 = "^";
String n3 = "~";
String[] operators = {n0, n1, n2, n3};
for (int i = 0; i < operators.length; i++) {
    String operator = operators[i];
    System.out.println(operator);
}
```

This code adds your variables to an array and then iterates over this array and prints the values saved in the array i.e. your variables.